# align a form to the center Using width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm totally new to the web development. I have a form and I want it in the middle of the content. My form width is `930px` and its heights are

```
min-height: 450px;
max-height: 860px;
```

So, I tried different ways but i wasn't able to do this. This may be a silly question but can any one please help me with this?

HTML is -

```
    <div class="container" ng-show="showthejdData">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="form-horizontal jdformCorners">

                            <!--ngFor-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="must" class="col-sm-2  ">MustRequirement</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control setmargin" id="must" placeholder="must requirement">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="should" class="col-sm-2">ShouldRequirement</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control setmargin" id="should" placeholder="should requirement">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="could" class="col-sm-2">CouldRequirement</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-5 setmargin">
                                    <input type="text" name="could" class="form-control setmargin" id="could" placeholder="could requirement"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    </form></div></div>


CSS- 

        .jdformCorners {
          border-radius: 25px;
            border: 2px solid #dddddd;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 932px;
            min-height: 450px;
            max-height: 860px;
        }
    .setmargin {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: `So, I tried different ways` What different ways?

Comment: I tried using the flex and also tried using css align property

Comment: Have you tried? `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: yes I tried with this as well

Comment: Please provide your source code, there is no solution that can fit all cases.

Comment: I have added the html

Comment: Please check now

Comment: To center your `<form>` element, just use `margin: 0 auto`. Unless you want to center all the `<div>` inside the `<form>`?

Comment: Also, in your given code there is a redundant tag `</textarea>`.

Comment: thanks for this.I tried your way but still I am not able to make it. I want all the form elemnts at the center

Answer (score 0):

you could use this :

```
#form1 {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin : 0 auto;
}
```

i also removed the width from .jdformCorners to be responsive
here is a jfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/f8ugLor9/5/

Comment: Hi her labels are coming at top. And I dont want that

Comment: Ok i edited the jsfiddle for you, i added a class to label and div that contain input fields .laabelInput{display : inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

Comment: hey here you used a form class can you please tell me in html where you have used this class ?

Comment: i used this class in labels and div tag that contains the input fields

Comment: .form class or just a fomr

Comment: look at the label tag and the div that contain the input fields, there's a class named laabelInput, that what i added

Comment: I added a .form in css and then used that .form in the div class="row form"

Comment: form {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin : 0 auto;
}  this one is creating me some problems because currently I have more than 5 forms so it is affecting on all the forms

Comment: i changed the jsfiddle, added an id to the form id="form1" and changed form to #form1 in the css

Answer (score 0):

hello my dear friend the best way for that is this way beacause with this way you can make it [responsive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) :

```css
.form{
  width:35%;/*or use what percantage do you want*/
  margin : 0 auto ;/*with this syntax you can centerlize your form*/
  display : block;/*this means this form must get full block*/
}

.innerform{
  display:block;
  margin : 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="innerform">
    <input />
  </div>
  <div class="innerform">
    <input />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to center using css. One simple way is to use `margin: 0 auto;` for items with `display` = `block` (and have its width smaller than its parent's width).

To center all the `<div>` element inside the `<form>`, you can add `display: flex` for `.jdformCorners`:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
```

See full source code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/d48tdsed/1/

Also, check out this website: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: its not in center

Comment: I've checked in FF, Chrome and IE. Or do you mean you want to align the content vertically?

Comment: You can achieve that by adding `justify-content: center;` to `.jdformCorners`. Check my new jsfiddle link, and the website howtocenterincss too!